# $(this) is selecting window object instead of clicked element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, this

I have a really strange issue. I simply want to select a clicked element. I did this a lot of times and it always worked but this time, the jQuery $(this) selector doesn't select the clicked element, it selects the window object. Please let me know, if you have an idea, what could be the reason for this. I am using jQuery 2.1.4 and Twitters Bootstrap 3.3.5

HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete-file"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> Löschen</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( () => {
   $('.delete-file').on('click', () => {
      let element = $(this);
      console.log(element);
    });
});
```

Console-Output:

```
n.fn.init [Window]
```

instead of:

```
n.fn.init [a.btn.btn-danger.btn-xs.delete-file]
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It's because you're using an arrow function. The scope of the contents of this function do not change as per a standard function definition. For `this` to work you'll need to change the logic:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('.delete-file').on('click', function() {
    let element = $(this);
    console.log(element);
  });
});
```

Alternatively you could keep the arrow function and retrieve a reference to the clicked element through the `target` property of the event that's raised:

```
$(document).ready( () => {
  $('.delete-file').on('click', e => {
    let element = $(e.target);
    console.log(element);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved the problem. I just realised, that this was the only thing I did different this time.

Comment: THANK YOU. I love finding stuff like this much later.